# Can't boot into GRUB (Win 11 and Linux installed on separate drives)

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have a Lenovo P330 Thinkstation.  This SSD it shipped with runs Win 11.  I wanted to experiment with Linux, so I installed an M.2 SSD and put first Mint and and then Ubuntu on it.  I booted via GRUB.  I then removed the M.2 drive, and changed the boot disk order in BIOS, but I was unable to boot into Win 11.  Reinstalling the M.2 drive didn't fix the problem.  I also changed some of the BIOS settings (CSM, secure boot) according to online help instructions elsewhere.  Those changes didn't fix the problem.  I think I have returned the BIOS settings to what they were before I removed the M.2 drive.

I thought, naively, removing the M.2 drive would force the machine to boot via the original SSD with Windows on it (I have a very cursory and clearly inadequate understanding of GRUB).  I need to access the SSD with Win 11 on it.  The M.2 with the two Linux distros is expendable.  Would reinstalling one of the Linux distros over the existing two fix the problem?  If not, I would appreciate suggestions as to how I can successfully boot into Windows.  I did see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324756/cant-boot-into-grub-dual-boot-with-win10) question, but I think my situation is a bit different, hence my question.

My current BIOS settings are:  
CSM:  Enabled
Boot Mode:  Auto
Boot Priority:  UEFI First
Secure Boot:  Disabled

I see a message about error 1962 (no operating system found) after the Lenovo splash page.

Comment: You will not be able to boot Windows 11 with SecureBoot disabled, you have to enable that before booting Windows 11. Also disable CSM, that is not necessary.

Comment: You're also not trying to boot into GRUB, but rather into Windows, as it seems. You should be able to boot Windows *through* GRUB, by booting into the Linux install, running `sudo os-prober` and then `sudo update-grub` and choosing Windows from the GRUB menu. You have to do this from within the Linux distro that is currently supplying GRUB.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  Changing to a secure boot didn't help.  Also, to clarify, I can't even get to a boot menu.  All is see is a message about error 1962 (see above) after the Lenovo splash page.

Comment: try selecting boot device in BIOS, does either drive appear there? Can you boot to a live USB and check on the drives that way?

Comment: Also, your Linux may have installed GRUB to the boot partition of Windows, which means you can either boot into GRUB and boot windows from there, or reinstall the Windows boot loader. You may also need to create a Windows live USB and repair Windows from it

Comment: When I look in the Primary Boot Sequence BIOS menu, I see the M.2 drive.  Interestingly, I don't actually see the Windows SSD, which I think should be associated with SATA 1.  The only other physical drive in that menu is the DVD drive (not relevant here).  Could this be the problem?

Comment: is the Windows drive connected properly? If you don't see it in BIOS, you won't be able to boot into it

Comment: I'll power down the machine and check.  It may take me a bit of time.  Thank you for your help to this point.  I will post an update once I've checked the drive physically.

Comment: So, I had a loose SATA connector.  I must have knocked it loose when I removed/re-installed the M.2.  When I power up, I boot directly into Win 11.  I don't see a GRUB menu, although if I hit F12, I can boot into GRUB and then into Mint.

Two questions:

1.  How do I restore the GRUB menu I used to see when I started up my machine?

2.  I still want to overwrite the M.2 with a fresh install of Mint that uses the entire drive (rather than share it with Ubuntu).   Would doing this affect the MBR on the Win 11 SSD in a way that prevents me from booting into Win 11?

Again, thank you.

Comment: New systems do not use MBR, they are UEFI and boot via the ESP -  efi system partition from gpt partitioned drives. And even if your vendor refers to system as BIOS, it really is UEFI as Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012. And now Windows 11 is only UEFI with Secure Boot. New Lenovo systems may also be UEFI only. Lenovo announced all 2020 products will be UEFI only (UEFI Class 3 or no CSM).
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht510878-legacy-bios-boot-support-removed-in-lenovo-2020-products

Comment: 1. Switch your BIOS boot priority to have the Linux drive as priority boot drive 2. You can just delete the partition that Mint is installed on, and extend the Ubuntu partition (assuming Mint provides the GRUB you're using, otherwise it gets trickier). Otherwise, installing Mint again on the whole drive shouldn't mess with anything

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Mint over the prior Mint and Ubuntu installations.  Everything is fine now.  Thanks again for all your help.